# Laravel 5 hasManyThrough repeating row content

Tags: laravel, orm, model, eloquent, has-many-through

I have the following Database tables:

```
tour
   idtour
    other_columns

day
   idday
   other_columns

tour_has_day
   idtour
   idday
```

Each tour has many days, and the days can be used in other tours

So, in the Tour.php model I add this function:

```
function days () {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Day', 'App\Tour_has_day', 'idtour', 'idday');
}
```

It gives me the correct number of related days but all rows have the same content

I debug the query that it returns:

```
select 
    `day`.*, 
    `tour_has_day`.`idtour` 
from `day` 
inner join 
    `tour_has_day` on `tour_has_day`.`idtour` = `day`.`idday`
where 
    `tour_has_day`.`idtour` = '1'
```

And it returns

[image: mysql workbench test]

Comment: That looks like a pivot table for which a many-to-many relation would be useful, not a has-many-through.

Comment: @JoelHinz Post it as answer and I check it as successful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a many-to-many relation with a pivot table like the one you have for that. The has-many-through relation is for when you have a parent and a child, and the child is the parent of another child.